# How do I forbid zend debugger from using cookies?

Tags: zend-debugger

It's causing lots of trouble,the cookies are not cleared after debugging!

how can I make it only use `$_GET` parameters?

Comment: You should accept some more answers.. 17% is not very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem with the debugger in Eclipse. I found that you can disable cookies on your browser to fix this. If your browser allows site only exceptions, like Google Chrome, you can block it just for your dev site without disturbing other site cookies.